# send delayed emails rails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, cron, heroku

I have a table in my database with a list of emails to be sent, each at a specific time (precision down to the minute).

I'm on heroku, and I don't want to spend anything right now.. Is there a way to do this? The only way I thought was to create a deamon/cron somewhere else and make it call a private url every minute.. any other idea? Any way to have some background process or something that can handle this (on Heroku and without paying extra for addons..)?

thanks!

Comment: Maybe heroku is a bad option for you.  I would recommend getting an inexpensive ($5ish/month) virtual machine.

Comment: What is the volume of emails you are sending out?

Comment: Not many mails, but I have to be exact in when they're sent. So probably there won't be more than a few at a single time, and very often none. I know heroku is not ideal for this without a worker but I wanted to try it, I already have an account on railsplayground..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's free cron addon runs only once a day, so it is not suitable. Their paid cron addon runs only once an hour, so it is also not suitable. Running a daemon/cron elsewhere is a hack that will become problematic very quickly. It's fundamentally bad architecture.

Using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) with a single Heroku Worker makes sense. Plus, delayed_job lets you specify exactly when each job should be run, down to a 5-second granularity. Yes, it is $36/mo to do this. But it frees you from doing things the wrong way. Plus, if you expect that you will not need the Worker most of the time, you can look into auto-scaling delayed_job on Heroku so the Worker is only turned on when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole bunch of free online services that would be more than happy to request your web page on a schedule that you set. You don't need to spend or code anything. Just Google :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Missed your request completelly :) But better late than never... The ones that I used in the past are http://scheduler.codeeffects.com and http://webbasedcron.com. The first has great UI. Others that I know are http://setcronjob.com and http://cronjobs.org